# Как в PostgreSQL просуммировать значения только по некоторым колонкам в таблице, исключая не нужные?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем привет.

У меня есть такая структура таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, имеется несколько колонок, значения по которым я должен просуммировать и по строчно для каждого opportinuty_id. Условно говоря, я могу руками сделать SELECT (col1 + col2 + col3), но как это сделать динамически для всех колонок, кроме некоторых? Ведь со временем кол-во колонок будет роста и не хочется каждый раз руками их добавлять в запрос - не по программистски.

Сам додуматься не могу. Смог вытащить список нужных мне названий колонок и сформировать из них массив. Но и тут не знаю, что делать дальше.

Comment: Данные надо правильно нормализовывать. Тогда запросы по годам месяцам и прочему будут писаться очень легко. А не вот это вот - добавим еще колонку. К 2025-му году будет 50 колонок?

Comment: Работая с БД, пора забыть Эксель и прочие табличные выверты. Конвертируйте в нормальное `(opportinuty_id, year_month, value)` - и запрос станет совершенно элементарным. Вот это будет по-программистски. А всё остальное есть фэ и моветон.

Comment: хм, в принципе замечание дельное. и хотя я и получил такие вот денормализованные данные и думал с ними поработать исходя из задачи, но скорее всего вы оба правы - надо данные нормализовать. правда теперь нужно подумать как эти данные правильно привести в рекомендованный вами порядок опять же кодом.

Comment: @Viktor Andriichuk вы не указали среду на которой строите уровень бизнес логики. Но в принципе достаточно и PostgreSQL я поставил расширение python и добавил библиотеку openpyxl. Это позволило мне втянуть файлы Excel с клиента на сервер с похожим форматом.  openpyxl позволяет вертеть как хочешь, гораздо удобнее чем библиотеки от MS.

Comment: да, я тоже из экселя через питон данные втягиваю в БД. но теперь думаю над тем, как нормализовать перед загрузкой в БД

Comment: Так вам базовый вариант структуры таблицы предложили во втором комментарии, берите его за основу и перегоняйте в нее. можно проверять задвоение данных, при наличии обновлять или ничего не делать по существующим месяцам года. Я так же сохраняю сами файлы и логи импорта, что бы потом если что концы найти.

Comment: Вообще-то я так и написал, что буду так делать.